# Calculate Previous Month From a String Input (React)

Tags: reactjs

```
I need to pass the Previous Month into a variable in an HTTP request.
```

Currently, I select a month from a `Drop List` and the variable fills with the value I choose.

Eg: if I choose;

```
Month - September
Year - 2020
```

if passes `September` and `2020` as into variables in the HTTP request.

There is another HTTP request which I need to pass the previous month of the selected month.

Eg: If I choose `September` `2020`, I need to fill the other HTTP request with `August` `2020`.

What's the best way to achieve this?

PS : Also something needs to keep in mind is, is the current month is `2020` `January`, when getting the previous month - it's should be `December` `2019`. So must consider the year as well in some cases.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Quick thought, store months as array and give array index as value to the select component. So if you get 9 from select you can get current and previous index from array easily.

Answer (score 1):

you can use `setMonth` and `getMonth`

```
myDisplayVar = selectedMonth.setMonth(selectedMonth.getMonth() - 1);
```

Comment: Thanks. What if the current month is 2020 January, when getting the previous month - it's should be December 2019.

Comment: I guess you can find out by trying :) It needs to work

Answer (score 0):

Use Date functions like Derviş Kayımbaşıoğlu said or use this way

```
getMonthBefore(month, year){
    const months = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"]
    const monthIndex = months.indexOf(month)
    if(monthIndex > 0){
      return {
        year: year,
        month: months[monthIndex-1]
      }
    }
    else{
      return {
        year: year-1,
        month: months[11]
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks. What if the current month is 2020 January, when getting the previous month - it's should be December 2019.